# Prevent Spring WebFlux WebClient from performing new exchange upon new subscription

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams, spring-webclient

The `DefaultWebClient` has the `exchange` implemented as:

```java
@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> exchange() {
    ClientRequest request = (this.inserter != null ?
            initRequestBuilder().body(this.inserter).build() :
            initRequestBuilder().build());
    return Mono.defer(() -> exchangeFunction.exchange(request)
            .checkpoint("Request to " + this.httpMethod.name() + " " + this.uri + " [DefaultWebClient]")
            .switchIfEmpty(NO_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE_ERROR));
}
```

As you can see above, the `exchangeFunction.exchange` call is wrapped by `Mono.defer`, hence it will be executed whenever something is subscribing to the returned `Mono<ClientResponse>`.

However, in my very specific use case, I do not want to re-execute the exchange given the below simplified code:

```java
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://some-base-url");
final AtomicReference<Mono<ClientResponse>> responseRef = new AtomicReference<>(null);
Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
    .flatMap(num -> {
        if (...some condition...) {
            return responseRef.updateAndGet(response -> response == null 
                                                        ? webClient.get().uri("/some-path").exchange()
                                                        : response)
                              .flatMap(response -> {...do something with num and response...});
        } else {
            return Mono.just(...something...);
        }
    })
    ...
```

As you can see above in my use case, I tried to use `AtomicReference` to get the `Mono<ClientResponse>` lazily so that the HTTP request will not be made again and again.

This does not work as expected since the do-something-with-num-and-response `flatMap` subscribing to the `Mono<ClientResponse>` published by `exchange()` will trigger its internal `exchangeFunction.exchange` again and again.

Can I wrap the published `Mono<ClientResponse>` with something to offset the effect of `Mono.defer`? Or is there anyway to work-around it without changing my use case's code structure?

**========== Workable Solution ==========**

Inspired by the accepted answer, I changed my code as follow to work:

```java
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://some-base-url");
final AtomicReference<Mono<ClientResponse>> responseRef = new AtomicReference<>(null);
Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
    .flatMap(num -> {
        if (...some condition...) {
            return responseRef.updateAndGet(response -> response == null 
                                                        ? webClient.get().uri("/some-path").exchange().cache()
                                                        : response)
                              .flatMap(response -> {...do something with num and response...});
        } else {
            return Mono.just(...something...);
        }
    })
    ...
```

Pay attention to the `cache()` after the `exchange()`. Cache of the `Mono` turns it into a hot source and cache last emitted signals for further subscribers. Completion and Error will also be replayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
Flux<String> data = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("test")
                .exchange()
                //do whatever you need on response
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class))
                .flux()
                //Turn this Flux into a hot source and cache last emitted signals for further Subscriber
                .replay()
                //Connects this ConnectableFlux to the upstream source when the first Subscriber subscribes.
                .autoConnect();

Flux.range(0, 10).flatMap(integer -> data).log().subscribe();
```

You can do:

```
 Mono<String> data = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("test")
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class))
                .cache();


 Flux.range(0, 10).flatMap(integer -> {
        if (integer % 2 == 0)
            return data;
        else
            return Mono.empty();
    }).log().subscribe();
```

Comment: In my use case, I do not want to execute the WebClient request beforehand.

Comment: you are not executing it, this will be executed when .flatMap(integer->data) subscribes first time

Comment: You can test it

Comment: So I assume that the important points are the `replay` and `autoConnect`? Let me give it a try.

Comment: So I figured that I have to convert the `Mono` to `Flux` which I don't quite want to... Since it is indeed a Mono of response not a Flux of n responses.

Comment: I noticed that in your code snippet you mentioned turning flux to hot source and cache last emitted signals. If I want to stay with `Mono`, can I use `Mono.cache` instead. According to `Mono.cache`'s javadocs it seems like having the same effect.

Comment: I tested with `Mono.cache` and it works as expected. Thanks!